# Extract title and add to post in Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, title

I have a Wordpress site with 500+ posts. I would like to extract the title of each post, wrap it with some span class code, add the title and code to the end of each post (the same post from which it was extracted), and hide its visibility. How would I go about doing this in Wordpress/PHP?

Thanks!

EDIT: @unixmiah, would this be achieved like so?

```
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 500, 'offset'=> 0, 'category' => 1 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <li span class="name hidden"><?php the_title();?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Which file do I insert this into? functions.php? Also, how do I ensure this code will run site-wide?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to accomplish this with wordpress internal functions to get that information in a loop.

For example

```
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 500, 'offset'=> 0, 'category' => 1 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

your javascript span question seems vague, do you mean to hide it and show it on mouseover?

Comment: I meant I would like to insert span class="class_name" HTML tags around the title, then hide it (using visibility: hidden CSS?).